# iOS - Core Data : How to properly add object in context while performing a Lightweight Migration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, migration

**Some context:**

I will try to explain my situation as clear as I can so that you will have a better understanding of my project and what I am willing to achieve.

First of all, the homepage of my App is split into "blocs".

Which mean it is an `UICollectionView`, and each cell is a "bloc" displaying specific information.

For example, I am working on a weather App, so the homepage will display different blocs :

- Classic forecast
- Satellite view
- Radar animation
- Sunrise/Sunset, Moonrise/Moonset
- Maps
  etc...

The user can order the blocs in the way he wants, remove or add some and the "*configuration*" will be saved according to the `city` he is currently looking at.

For example, you can have London in a favorite city, with specific homepage configuration.

**The issue:**

The default configuration of the homepage is a `plist` in the App, which indicates the type of the tile if the tile can be delectable, moveable etc...

I have an Enum for the tile type.

[image]

**Core Data:**

I have 2 important entities in Core Data :

- CDCity
- CDTile (the blocs)

It is important to notice the relationship between those entities.

This is **CDTile**
[image]

And this is **CDCity**

[image]

To put it in a nutshell, all our specific bloc type inherit from CDTile, which is linked with CDCity.

I have created an extension to the default CDCity file, which is called CDCity+Additions.

Here I am calling this :

```
-(void)awakeFromInsert
{
    [super awakeFromInsert];

    // create the default homepage configuration for the current city.
    [self createDefaultTilesWithContext:self.managedObjectContext];
}
```

It is the core method of the feature :

```
-(void)createDefaultTilesWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)ctxt
{
    NSString * tilesConfigPath = [[NSString alloc] init];
    tilesConfigPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tilesDefaultConfig" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSArray * tilesConfig = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:tilesConfigPath];

    for (NSDictionary *config in tilesConfig) {
        NSNumber *tileType = [config objectForKey:TILE_CONFIG_KEY_TYPE];
        NSString *tileEntity = nil;

        switch (tileType.intValue) {

            case TileRegionalForecast:
                tileEntity = @"CDRegionalForecastTile";
                break;

            case TileNextDays:
                tileEntity = @"CDNextDaysTile";
                break;

            case TileRadar:
                tileEntity = @"CDRadarTile";
                break;

            case TileSatellite:
                tileEntity = @"CDSatelliteTile";
                break;

            case TileRainInTheHour:
                tileEntity = @"CDRainInTheHourTile";
                break;

            case TileMountainForecast:
                tileEntity = @"CDMountainTile";
                break;

            default:
                NSLog(@"Unknown tile : %@", tileType);
                break;
        }

        if (nil != tileEntity) {
            CDTile *c = (CDTile*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:tileEntity inManagedObjectContext:ctxt];
            [c initWithConfigDict:config];
            c.city = self;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I init the tile from the pList parameters :

```
-(void)initWithConfigDict:(NSDictionary *)configDict
{
    self.type = [configDict objectForKey:TILE_CONFIG_KEY_TYPE];
    self.moveable = [configDict objectForKey:TILE_CONFIG_KEY_MOVEABLE];
    self.deletable = [configDict objectForKey:TILE_CONFIG_KEY_DELETABLE];
    self.index = [configDict objectForKey:TILE_CONFIG_KEY_DEFAULT_INDEX];
    self.widthRatio = [configDict objectForKey:TILE_CONFIG_KEY_WIDTH_RATIO];
}
```

**The REAL question :**

What if I want to add an other tile in the default configuration, for a new feature for example.

**What I am doing :**

I create the new entity **CDMyNewTile**, with **CDTile** as parent entity in Core Data, in a new xcdatamodel version. Which will be handled as a lightweight migration because I am only adding an entity, nothing complex.

I then add the item to my plist for de default configuration and in my Enum of tile type.

Finally this is the method I have created :

```
-(void)createNewTileIfNeededWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSString * tilesConfigPath = [[NSString alloc] init];

    tilesConfigPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tilesDefaultConfig" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSArray * tilesConfig = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:tilesConfigPath];

    NSSet *newTile = [self.tiles filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == %@", @(NewTileType)]];

    if (0 == [newTile count]) {
        // The new tile isn't in the context, we add it

        CDNewTile *newTile = (CDNewTile *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDNewTile" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [self addTilesObject: newTile];
        [newTile initWithConfigDict:[tilesConfig objectAtIndex:12]]; //index in plist
        newTile.city = self;
        newTile.eligible = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    }
}
```

But I don't really know when to call this method, should I create a method like this for every entity I want to add in my context ?

Because here is the issue:

- An user have saved some cities as favorites, with specific configurations.
- When he will update the app, for every not saved cities as favorite, the default homePage configuration will be applied, and then my new bloc will be added.
- But how to update the configuration of the favorite cities ? I mean, add my new bloc to the favorite cities ?

I feel like CoreData is a powerful tool, but sometimes it is very complicated for just simple action.

How to simply add an entity to the context, so that the lightweight migration process handles everything, and even old context get updated?

**EDIT:**

This is in my AppDelegate, to enable the lightweight migration :

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"****.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    // Create a dictionary for automatic lightweight core data migration
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                             nil];

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    // Set up the persistent store and migrate if needed
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like your `-createNewTileIfNeededWithContext:` method is not getting called at the right time. How is that being invoked on existing cities?

Comment: Can you share how you are doing lightweight migration? The exact code?

Comment: @ArunB I have update my question. Refer to the EDIT part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html).

> If you just make simple changes to your model (such as adding a new attribute to an entity), Core Data can perform automatic data migration, referred to as lightweight migration. Lightweight migration is fundamentally the same as ordinary migration, except that instead of you providing a mapping model (as described in Mapping Overview), Core Data infers one from differences between the source and destination managed object models.

So once you associate the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` with the new `NSManagedObjectModel`, the updated models will be migrated based on the migration option. In this case, automatically. Hence, anywhere after you have called the `persistentStoreCoordinator` method, you can call the `createNewTileIfNeededWithContext` method.

Comment: I agree with this point, but I don't see in my situation where exactly should I call the persistentStoreCoordinator method ? In order to do what ?

Comment: In your Appdelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions, setup managedObjectModel and then call persistentStoreCoordinator method. That should set your CoreData stack with the migration.

Comment: Ok so basically I already did this. I will call my createNewTileIfNeededWithContext but it will be applied only at the first release ? When everyone will be updated with the new xcdatamlodelVersion this method will be useless right ?

Comment: Yes it will be useless when everyone has new xcdatamlodelVersion